# Get Logback pattern inside java code

Tags: java, logging, logback

I'm inserting some vars via MDC, but I want to log a WARN if this var is not used in logback pattern. Does anyone know how to retrieve the logback pattern in java code? Sth. like this:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.MDC;
...

...
Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTestClass.class);
...

MDC.put("id","thisIsATestId");
String pattern = LOG.getLogbackPattern();
checkPatternAndWarnIfMissingVar(pattern,"id");
...
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit ugly, which probably signals that we're not meant to do it, but it appears to work:

```
// Get some internal contexts
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logger = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger)
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);

// Get the current pattern in the appender.
OutputStreamAppender<ILoggingEvent> consoleapp = 
    (OutputStreamAppender<ILoggingEvent>) logger.getAppender("console");

// Now check the pattern
PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = (PatternLayoutEncoder) consoleapp.getEncoder();
String pattern = encoder.getPattern();
checkPatternAndWarnIfMissingVar(pattern,"id");
```

Note that this assumes an appender named "console". The list of appenders depend on your configuration and can be retrieved using:

```
Iterator<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> it = logger.iteratorForAppenders();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Appender<ILoggingEvent> app = it.next();
    System.out.println( app.getName() );
}
```

Comment: For me, this does not work. I can not cast to OutputStreamAppender<ILoggingEvent> because the retrieved logger is a custom class of my used Framework extending ch.qos.logback.core.AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent>

Comment: I use the following imports: java.util.Iterator;ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder;ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;ch.qos.logback.core.Appender;ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender;

Comment: Which class exactly is your logger, then?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: io.dropwizard.logging.AsyncAppender cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender

Comment: I changed console to async-console-appender, what I get, if I run the System.out.println( app.getName() );

Answer (score 0):

Updating Henrik's answer, I got it to work like this:

```java
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder;

private String getPattern() {
    Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);

    OutputStreamAppender<ILoggingEvent> consoleAppender =
            (OutputStreamAppender<ILoggingEvent>) logger.getAppender("CONSOLE");

    PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = (PatternLayoutEncoder) consoleAppender.getEncoder();
    return encoder.getPattern();
}
```